# xmodmap alternative for the text console (TTY)?

Tags: keyboard, customization, keyboard-layout

There is a keyboard with <kbd>'</kbd> key broken. I've remapped it to the <kbd>Wake</kbd> button with `xmodmap` but that affects only X session, how can I achieve this for TTYs?

Note: editing keymap files directly is not the best option since I want the system to be upgradeable.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a way to rebind keys for a TTY without some serious tinkering..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't had to deal with a situation like yours nor am I sure about the 'Wake' button, but you may want to look into:

- /etc/inputrc or .inputrc
- loadkeys/dumpkeys

Comment: that might work, let me check... :)

Comment: yes, `showkey` to check the needed keycode (isn't the same for Xorg in my case), `dumpkeys` to get current values and `sudo loadkeys file-with-only-new-values`